# Reduce time delay on Resume

Tags: android, libgdx

I have a simple libgdx code for game which contains 1 texture and a particle effect with 4 emitters.
Whenever I resume to the game screen or lock-unlock the phone, I get a delay of about 3 seconds.
How do I reduce this delay?
One thing I have tried is that by reducing the texture image size.
Before i had a texture image of 300kb and used to get a delay of 5 seconds, now i hve reduced it to 60kb
and now I get a delay of 3 seconds.
Is there any way programaticaly that I can reduce the delay. I dont want to show any spalsh screen
Code:

```
    @Override
    public void show() {
        SpriteBatch batch = new SpriteBatch();
        Texture tex = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/bg1.jpg"));
        Sprite sprite = new Sprite(tex);

        ParticleEffect pe = new ParticleEffect();
        pe.load(Gdx.files.internal("data/pe1.p"), Gdx.files.internal("data"));
        pe.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
        gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, (int) Width, (int) Height);

        camera.update();
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        batch.begin();
            sprite.draw(batch);
            pe.draw(batch, delta);
        batch.end();
    }
```

Comment: Please find out where time is lost. `long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis(); <some code>; long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis(); ...` and finally print all `t`-s to the log (or, better, the differences like `t3-t2`).

Comment: How does your `pause()` and `resume()` method look like?

Comment: I hav nothing in pause() and resume() methods, they are blank.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just try making the local variables in show() field variables and initializing them in the constructor rather than in the show method. I would still recommend measuring which part is taking the most time as the one comment states.